# JerseyApplication bindFactory ranked attribute does not get considered in tests

Tags: java, jersey, hk2

For testing purposes I like to replace a factory in my JerseyApplication with a different factory and unfortunately the proper binding does not get considered and always utilises the defined factory within `JerseyApplication.class`

Here's the following setup in `JerseyApplication`, via `org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.AbstractBinder`

```
   private class ProductionBinder extends AbstractBinder {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {

        //Production Factory
        bindFactory(SpecificClientFactory.class).to(SpecificClient.class).in(RequestScoped.class);
    }
   }
```

Within my base test class, I am setting it up with the same `AbstractBinder` and it works perfectly fine for all *bind().to().in().ranked(1)* but not for the *bindFactory*, such as below:

```
public class BaseAPITest extends AbstractApiTest {

@Override
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
}

@Override
protected ResourceConfig createApplication() {
    final JerseyApplication app = new JerseyApplication();
    app.register(new MockBinder());
    return app;
}

class MockBinder extends AbstractBinder {
    @Override
    protected void configure(){

        //Test Factory
        bindFactory(TestSpecificClientFactory.class).to(SpecificClient.class).in(RequestScoped.class).ranked(1);
    }
}
```

}

Am I missing a crucial property/setting?

Thanks

Comment: I wonder if it's a bug with Jersey. Can you try it with the hk2 AbstractBinder?

Comment: So it seems it is a Jersey problem. You can see [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/psamsotha/d7f782fff4a9be7b04f80fdde416294e). It works fine when I am using the HK2 `AbstractBinder`. It fails on the Jersey one.